# Python3 vs Python2 list/generator range performance

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, generator

I have this simple function that partitions a list and returns an index i in the list such that elements at indices less that i are smaller than list[i] and elements at indices greater than i are bigger.

```
def partition(arr):
    first_high = 0
    pivot = len(arr) - 1
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < arr[pivot]:
            arr[first_high], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[first_high]
            first_high = first_high + 1

    arr[first_high], arr[pivot] = arr[pivot], arr[first_high]
    return first_high


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [1, 5, 4, 6, 0, 3]
    pivot = partition(arr)
    print(pivot)
```

The runtime is substantially bigger with python 3.4 that python 2.7.6
on OS X:

```
time python3 partition.py
real 0m0.040s
user 0m0.027s
sys  0m0.010s

time python partition.py
real 0m0.031s
user 0m0.018s
sys  0m0.011s
```

Same thing on ubuntu 14.04 / virtual box

python3:

```
real 0m0.049s
user 0m0.034s
sys  0m0.015s
```

python:

```
real 0m0.044s
user 0m0.022s
sys  0m0.018s
```

Is python3 inherently slower that python2.7 or is there any specific optimizations to the code do make run as fast as on python2.7

Comment: Use the `timeit` module to compare code execution, not `time`; Python startup time is overrepresented, as are random OS events such as disk flushes.

Comment: I was trying your code when I realized, what is `lasthigh`? Out of the box that code will fail because `lasthigh` is not initialized? Please review.

Comment: @PauloBu you're right. there no lasthigh it is actually first_high. Fixed thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be benchmarking with `timeit` rather than with OS tools.

My guess is the `range` function is probably performing a little slower in Python 3. In Python 2 it simply returns a [list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?#range), in Python 3 it returns a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) which behave more or less like a generator. I did some benchmarking and this was the result, which may be a hint on what you're experiencing:

```
python -mtimeit "range(10)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.474 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit "range(10)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.59 usec per loop

python -mtimeit "range(100)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit "range(100)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.578 usec per loop

python -mtimeit "range(1000)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.6 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit "range(1000)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.66 usec per loop
```

As you can see, when input provided to `range` is *small*, it tends to be fast in Python 2. If the input grows, then Python 3's  `range` behave better.

My suggestion: test the code for larger arrays, with a hundred or a thousand elements.

Actually, I went further and test a complete iteration through the elements. The results were totally in favor of Python 2:

```
python -mtimeit "for i in range(1000):pass"
10000 loops, best of 3: 31 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit "for i in range(1000):pass"
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.3 usec per loop

python -mtimeit "for i in range(10000):pass"
1000 loops, best of 3: 330 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit "for i in range(10000):pass"
1000 loops, best of 3: 480 usec per loop
```

My conclusion is that, is probably faster to iterate through a list than through a generator. Although the latter is definitely more efficient regarding memory consumption. This is a classic example of the trade off between speed and memory. Although the speed difference is not *that big* per se (less than miliseconds). So you should value this and what's better for your program.

Comment: I'm not at my computer so I can't check, but I think you should try your second benchmark with very large numbers (say, 10 million to a billion). I hypothesise that the upfront allocation that Python 2's `range` performs will kill the performance in the limiting case.

Comment: Python 3 implementation seems to be optimized for very large ranges then! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Python 3 `range()` should be compared with Python 2 `xrange()`. It does not generate the list first, it only iterates through the values. This way, it also does not consume more memory for bigger range.

Comment: Looping through the list may be optimized as the number of elements is known in advance. Actually, the loop need not to be stopped by the `StopIteration` exception -- this way the loop need not test whether exception happened (simpler code). But this is just my guess.

Comment: Using Python 2's range with a billion integer will explode the memory since it will need ~4GB to store the list. This is exactly when Python3's `range` or Python2's `xrange` come handy. The kind of tradeoff I mentioned in the answer.